# Consider the space $L^2$ and let $V(x)(t)=\int\limits_0^tx(s)ds$ be a linear operator, what is the conjugate operator $V^*$ of $V$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $L^2[0,1]$ and let $V(x)(t)=\int\limits_0^tx(s)ds$ be a linear operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$, what is the conjugate operator of $V$?

I know the dual space is the same, and if $g\in {L^2}^*$ is a linear and continuous function then $V^*(g)=f\in {L^2}^*$ where $f(x)=g(\int\limits_0^tx(s)ds)$, but I dont know how to find that function.

**My attempt:**

I know that if $g\in{L^2}^*$ then $g(x)=\int\limits_0^1y(t)x(t)dt$ for some unique $y\in{L^2}$.

Then $V^*(g)=f$ where $f=g(Vx)=g(\int\limits_0^tx(s)ds)=\int\limits_0^1y(t)\int\limits_0^tx(s)dsdt$

Just left to find the element $w\in L^2$ such that $\int\limits_0^1y(t)\int\limits_0^tx(s)dsdt=\int\limits_0^1w(t)x(t)dt$ so I can find the function $y\mapsto w$

Comment: $(L^2)^*$ is indeed $L^2$.

Comment: yes, but i have no idea how to translate a functional on ${L^2}^*$ to a funcion in ${L^2}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: I didn't know that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, thanks.

Comment: Oh yes! The inner product that induces the norm is given by $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ and it is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(Vx,y) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} x(s)  \;ds \cdot \overline{y(t)}\;dt = \int_{0}^{1} \overline{y(t)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[0,t]}(s) x(s) \;ds \;dt =\\ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[s,1]}(t) x(s)\overline{y(t)} \:dt \;ds = \int_{0}^{1} x(s) \cdot \int_{s}^{1} \overline{y(t)} \;dt \;ds = \int_{0}^{1} x(s) \cdot \overline{\int_{s}^{1} y(t) \;dt} \;ds = (x, V^{*}y)$$

Where $$(V^{*}y)(s) := \int_{s}^{1}y(t) \; dt$$

Comment: What did you do when you change $\chi_{[0,t]}$ for $\chi_{[s,1]}$?

Comment: Obeserve that the function $\chi_{[0,t]}(s)$ is equal to one if and only if $\chi_{[s,1]}(t)$ is equal to one.

Comment: Note that the third equality is Fubini's theorem, and its hypotheses have to be verified.